# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'life' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

hace unas semanas empezé con Python 3, estoy intentando hacer un pequeño juego que basicamente es por suerte, pero no al ejecutarlo sale un error que no entiendo, y no sé como solucionarlo. El código es:

```
#Before
n = int(0)
#Variables
life = int(5)
#Modules
import random
#Functions
def rnd():
    n = random.randint(0,1)
def gameMini():
    print("Use WASD to move, then ENTER to do the action")
    print("Y = You")
    print("  W")
    print("A Y S")
    print("  D")
    print("Move now with WASD")
    loca = str(input(""))
    if loca == "w":
        rnd()
        life = int(life) - int(n)
    if loca == "a":
        rnd()
        life = int(life) - int(n)
    if loca == "s":
        rnd()
        life = int(life) - int(n)
    if loca == "d":
        rnd()
        life = int(life) - int(n)
    if int(n == 1):
        life = int(life) - int(n)
        print("perdiste una vida")
        print(life)
        gameMini()
        input("")
    if int(n == 0):
        life = int(life) - int(n)
        print("No perdiste nada")
        print(life)
        gameMini()
        input("")
#Code
gameMini()
```

Y me sale como deberia funcionar, es menú del juego (bueno es el propio juego pero no importa):

```
Use WASD to move, then ENTER to do the action
Y = You
  W
A Y S
  D
Move now with WASD
```

Pero, al poner "w" para que haga la función, sale esto:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Roger\Desktop\ss.py", line 43, in <module>
    gameMini()
  File "C:\Users\Roger\Desktop\ss.py", line 37, in gameMini
    life = int(life) - int(n)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'life' referenced before assignment
```

Intenté todo lo que pude como moviendo las variables antes de todo el código principal, pero sigue sin funcionar. Por favor, ayudenme

Comment: Te falta un `global life` al empezar la definición de `gameMini`. Sin ella, `life` es una variable local a la función `gameMini`, no la variable global que definiste afuera.

Comment: Gracias! Ahora si funciona, y ya lo puedo terminar :)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que especificar que se esta usando una variable global, que se declaro fuera de la función, te dejo el ejemplo que aplica en tu caso

```
def gameMini():
   global life
   print("Use WASD to move, then ENTER to do the action")
   print("Y = You")
   ...
```